# How to convert a string of numbers in pandas to integer

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion

I'm trying to find out a way to convert this string of bounding box coordinates to a list of integers. Every idea I have throws a KeyError, any tips?

```
for row in bounding_image_df['bounding_box']:
    bounding_image_df['bounding_box'][row] = list(map(int, bounding_image_df['bounding_box'][row].split(' ')))
```

```
for row in bounding_image_df['bounding_box']:
    bounding_image_df['bounding_box'][row] = bounding_image_df['bounding_box'][row].split(' ')
```

```
for row in bounding_image_df['bounding_box']:
    pd.to_numeric(bounding_image_df['bounding_box'][row], errors='ignore')
```

These all throw the same error, a key error with the only description being the unconverted string in the first row of the dataframe.

```
KeyError: '60 127 253 72'
```

Comment: try `df['bounding_box'].str.replace(''', '')` before you call your `to_numeric` you need to clean your string type data first or force it into an `NaN` with `errors='coerce'`

Comment: I've tried that before, sadly no dice. Just the same KeyError over and over.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with sample data and your expected output. You probably don't need to loop like that, and there's a lot of bad `chained indexing` happening in your code. But what I can say is you're getting a key error because in `bounding_image_df['bounding_box'][row]` `row` is the Value in the cell, yet you are trying to use that to slice the Index of your Series. This doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df['bounding_box'].map(lambda x: x.split(', ')
```

Or perhaps:

```
df['bounding_box'].map(lambda x: x.replace(' ', '').split(','))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've understood you have a dataframe like this:

```
dicc = {'colum1': ['row1', 'row2', 'row3'],
        'bounding_box': ['60 127 253 72','55 137 243 22','56 227 113 78']
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(dicc)
df
```

Then, if you want to convert the column 'bounding box' to int, I would use:

```
df['bounding_box']=df['bounding_box'].str.split(' ').apply(lambda x: [int(num) for num in x])
```

Then if you print(df), you'll get:

```
colum1  bounding_box
0   row1    [60, 127, 253, 72]
1   row2    [55, 137, 243, 22]
2   row3    [56, 227, 113, 78]
```